# React native wheel of fortune package

Tags: react-native, svg, expo

the text is not aligned in the center of the spikes, I tried to increase the size and changing the text angle property but nothing is helping, can you help with that, I have attached the picture[image]

should be like this
[image]

SpinWheel.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

import WheelOfFortune from "react-native-wheel-of-fortune";

const participants = [
  "%10",
  "%20",
  "%30",
  "%40",
  "%50",
  "%60",
  "%70",
  "%80",
  "%90",
  "FREE",
];

class SpinWheel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      winnerValue: null,
      winnerIndex: null,
      started: false,
    };
    this.child = null;
  }

  buttonPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      started: true,
    });
    this.child._onPress();
  };
  render() {
    const wheelOptions = {
      rewards: participants,
      knobSize: 50,
      borderWidth: 5,
      borderColor: "#fff",
      innerRadius: 50,
      duration: 4000,
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      textAngle: "horizontal",
      textFontSize: 55,
      knobSource: require("../assets/images/knob.png"),
      onRef: (ref) => (this.child = ref),
    };

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WheelOfFortune
          options={wheelOptions}
          getWinner={(value, index) => {
            this.setState({ winnerValue: value, winnerIndex: index });
          }}
        />
        {!this.state.started && (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.buttonPress()}
            style={styles.startButton}
          >
            <Text style={styles.startButtonText}>Start</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        {this.state.winnerIndex != null && (
          <View style={styles.winnerView}>
            <Text style={styles.winnerText}>
              You win {participants[this.state.winnerIndex]}
            </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                this.setState({ winnerIndex: null });
                this.child._tryAgain();
              }}
              style={styles.tryAgainButton}
            >
              <Text style={styles.tryAgainText}>TRY AGAIN</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default SpinWheel;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 150,
  },
  startButton: {
    marginTop: 250,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 10,
  },
  startButtonText: {
    color: "blue",
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  winnerView: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  tryAgainButton: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  winnerText: {
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  tryAgainButton: {
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
  },
  tryAgainText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#fff",
  },
});
```

I am a new learner of react native and it is very frustrating when the problem is not getting solved.